# Why can't we trivially copy std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

The reason for me to ask this is I need to store `std::function` in a vector, and the in-house vector we have in company basically is doing realloc if it needs more memory. (Basically just `memcpy`, no copy/move operator involves)

This means all the element we can put in our container need to be trivially-copyable.

Here is some code to demonstrate the problematic copy I had:

```
void* func1Buffer = malloc(sizeof(std::function<void(int)>));
std::function<void(int)>* func1p = new (func1Buffer) std::function<void(int)>();
std::function<void(int)>* func2p = nullptr;
*func1p = [](int) {};
char func2Buffer[sizeof(*func1p)];
memcpy(&func2Buffer, func1p, sizeof(*func1p));
func2p = (std::function<void(int)>*)(func2Buffer);
// func2p is still valid here
(*func2p)(10);
free(func1Buffer);
// func2p is now invalid, even without std::function<void(int)> desctructor get triggered
(*func2p)(10);
```

I understand we should support copy/move of the element in order to store `std::function` safely.
But I am still very curious about what is the direct cause of invalid `std::function` copy above.

**----------------------------------------------------UpdateLine----------------------------------------------------**

Updated the code sample.

I have found the direct reason for this failure, by debugging our in-house vector more.

The trivially copied `std::function` has some dependency on original object memory, delete the original memory will trash the badly copied `std::function` even **without** the destruction of the original object.

Thanks for everyone's answer to this post. It's all valuable input. :)

Comment: *Why can't we trivially copy std::function*? Because the standard defines it that way.

Comment: As long as you are using non capturing lambdas you can get away with storing function pointers in the vector.

Comment: some update here, I made some mistake locally and the code sample I give in my question is actually working.

Comment: In practice, it's because the function object contains internal pointers to other parts of itself. Memcpying the object leaves those pointers dangling.

Comment: @RaymondChen, yes, this one is valid. and I have easily got a crash by use func2p after desotry func1.

Comment: `delete func1Buffer;` <-- you can't `delete` a `void*`, and you shouldn't `delete` memory that was acquired from `malloc()`.

Comment: @Barry Code updated, thanks for point it out.

Comment: Also your code example now makes zero sense. Of course the call is invalid - we're pointed to freed memory. That's invalid even if `func2p` was a `char*`.

Comment: func2p is pointed to func2Buffer, what I freed is func1Buffer, func2Buffer was copied from func1Buffer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is how `std::function` has to be implemented: it has to manage the lifetime of whatever object it's holding onto. So when you write:

```
{
    std::function<Sig> f = X{};
}
```

we must invoke the destructor of `X` when `f` goes out of scope. Moreover, `std::function` will [potentially] allocate memory to hold that `X` so the destructor of `f` must also [potentially] free that memory.

Now consider what happens when we try to do:

```
char buffer[100000]; // something big
{
    std::function<void()> f = X{};
    memcpy(buffer, &f, sizeof(f));
}
(*reinterpret_cast<std::function<void()>*>(buffer))();
```

At the point we're calling the function "stored" at `buffer`, the `X` object has already been destroyed and the memory holding it has been [potentially] freed. Regardless of whether `X` were `TriviallyCopyable`, we don't have an `X` anymore. We have the artist formerly known as an `X`.

Because it's incumbent upon `std::function` to manage its own objects, it cannot be `TriviallyCopyable` *even if* we added the requirement that all callables it managed were `TriviallyCopyable`.

---

To work in your `realloc_vector`, you need either need something like `function_ref` (or `std::function<>*`) (that is, a type that simply doesn't own any resources), or you need to implement your own version of `function` that (a) keeps its own storage as a member to avoid allocating memory *and* (b) is only constructible with `TriviallyCopyable` callables so that it itself becomes trivially copyable. Whichever solution is better depends on the what your program is actually doing.

Answer (score 4):

> But I am still very curious about what is the direct cause of invalid
>   std::function copy above.

`std::function` cannot be [`TriviallyCopyable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable) (or conditionally `TriviallyCopyable`) because as a generic callable object wrapper it cannot assume that the stored callable is `TriviallyCopyable`.

Consider implementing your own version of `std::function` that only supports `TriviallyCopyable` callable objects (using a fixed buffer for storage), or use a vector of function pointers if applicable in your situation.

Comment: The problem is not so much that whatever is stored might not be trivially copyable, but that it has to allocate that object on the heap

Answer (score 3):

To be trivially copyable is something that is inherently related to a given type, not to an object.
Consider the following example:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<functional>

int main() {
    auto l = [](){};
    static_assert(not std::is_trivially_copyable<decltype(l)>::value, "!");

    std::function<void(void)> f;
    bool copyable = std::is_trivially_copyable<decltype(f)>::value;
    f = l;

    // do something based on the
    // fact that f is trivially copyable
}
```

How could you enforce the property once you have assigned to the function the lambda, that is not trivially copyable?

What you are looking for would be a runtime machinery that gets a decision based on the actual object assigned to the function.
This is not how `std::is_trivially_copyable` works.
Therefore the compiler has to make a decision at compile-time regarding the given specialization for the `std::function`. For it's a generic container for callable objects and you can assign it trivially copyable objects as well as objects that aren't trivially copyable, the rest goes without saying.

Answer (score 2):

A std::function might allocate memory for captured variables. As with any other class which allocates memory, it's not trivially copyable.

Comment: It's not only that, an empty object could also be non-`TriviallyCopyable`.